# How to update applicationhost.config programmatically

Tags: iis, web-config

During the deploy to production we have to add a number of additional entries to the application's web.config, for example adding subkeys to  `system.identityModel/identityConfiguration/audienceUris`, which is declared at the top of the web.config file as

```
   <configSections>
     <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection,
 System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />   
   </configSections>
```

In an ideal world we would do this using config transforms at build time, but we've made a design decision to use msdeploy parameters instead, which don't allow the injection of XML nodes in parameters (in spite of various posts that suggest you can). There are solutions that allow you to use both but we don't have time to integrate those into our deployment infrastructure right now.

Ideally we would achieve our end using appcmd to add nodes in the msdeploy post-sync task, but it seems that out of the box appcmd does not expose these custom sections unless you also declare them in applicationhost.config.

Is there a way to use appcmd or other tools to programmatically update applicationhost.config to add these declarations or do we just have to work with the XML directly?

Comment: Hi, have you found the answer for this question? I'm also trying to achieve the same here ...

Comment: Sort of. We have another (non-web) application that had to be deployed via MSDeploy, and without using MSDeploy parameters - it was essentially an xcopy deployment. To achieve this I wrote a PowerShell script that unzipped the package to a temp location, applied a named config transform to the .exe.config file using the XDT DLL, and then used msdeploy to copy the application files and transformed config file to the target machine. Not at work right now, but I can share details if more needed.